What's the shortcut to toggle the "rotation" cross in the 3D view of OpenSCAD?
I have, at some moment, misfocused in openSCAD while typing and since then, a pinkish rotation cross has appeared in the 3D view (the one on the left, I don't know what's the exact name for that sort of thing).
How can I disable that?
I didn't see any option in the settings nor in the buttons below 3D view (which allow to disable the graduated axis, but gives nothing for that new pinkish/purplish cross)
Thanks!


Ctrl+Shift+3 on a FR (French) keyboard.
Brute force helped, I should have tried from the start!
